# Create image annotation of pdf using MuPDF on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, pdf, mupdf

I'm developing an WinRT application on C++ which should help users to read and annotate the PDF file. I'm using MuPDF to parse the PDF. I'm able to read the PDF and add lines and free text annotations but unable to insert an image to page. I couldn't find any sample nor could I find any manuals that explains what I am looking for.
I'm using the following code to create an image but image isn't appearing:

```
std::string pathToOutputBook3 += "\\testPDF.pdf";
std::string pathToImage3 = "Assets/hortitsa.jpg";

fz_point pts[4] = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 600, 0 }, { 600, 499 } };
fz_rect rect = fz_empty_rect;
pdf_document *pdfDoc = (pdf_document *)this->mu_doc;
pdf_page *pdfPage = (pdf_page *)page;
image_document *imgDoc = (image_document *)fz_open_document(this->mu_ctx, pathToImage3.c_str());
fz_image *image = imgDoc->image;
fz_matrix page_ctm = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };

fz_include_point_in_rect(&rect, &pts[0]);
fz_include_point_in_rect(&rect, &pts[1]);
fz_include_point_in_rect(&rect, &pts[2]);
fz_include_point_in_rect(&rect, &pts[3]);

display_list = fz_new_display_list(this->mu_ctx);
dev = fz_new_list_device(this->mu_ctx, display_list);

auto annot = pdf_create_annot(pdfDoc, pdfPage, fz_annot_type::FZ_ANNOT_SQUARE);

fz_fill_image(dev, image, &page_ctm, 1.0f);

fz_transform_rect(&rect, &page_ctm);
pdf_set_annot_appearance(pdfDoc, annot, &rect, display_list);

fz_write_document(this->mu_doc, (char *)pathToOutputBook3.c_str(), nullptr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'image' annotation type. There are annotation types which might be abused to store an image in the appearance, but readers which ignore the appearance stream and create new ones from the annotation dictionary (eg Adobe Acrobat) will still not display the image.

If you want to add an image to a document then you need to do that, not try to use an annotation. I believe it is now possible to add an image to the page contents stream using MuPDF, but I don't know how to do that myself.

Comment: When I was looking through the annotations of the PDF document with some images added with other PDF reader, the images were displayed as FZ_ANNOT_SQUARE. Could they be drawn not with MuPDF? Then why we need the methods image_open_document, image_run_page, fz_fill_image if they let upload the photo, but don't let it be displayed?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not a MuPDF developer, I'm just passing on comments from them, if you 'd like to talk to the developers then I'd recommend coming to the #ghostscript channel on irc.freenode.net.. I imagine that the methods you mention are used for purposes other than annotations. Without seeing the PDF file you are talking about I can't possibly comment on how its constructed.